# image postion is changing in IE and other browsers

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using below css class for the position of my image, but it place it fine in chrome, mozila and edge but in IE its showin on little displaced.Is there any way to fix the postion of image in all browser?

I have second question that using negative value to adjust image like in my css Top=-25px is fine?

html part :

```
 <td style="position: relative; width: 28%;">
   <div runat="server" id="CdLogo" class="cd-logo-mc">&nbsp;</div>
 </td>
```

CSS part -

```
  .cd-logo-mc {
        position: absolute;
        top: -25px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 60px;
        background-image: url('../content/images/image.png');
        background-position-x: center;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a fully working code snippet. Also IE will be deprecated starting at 17th August 2021 by Microsoft. It might be wasted efford to specifically support that browser at this point.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for your advice.i am adding the html part as well where i am calling this css class.i just want to know that if i use negative value in top=-25px , is it fine?